# Usage Reports empty

Tags: 2013, crawling, reports

I want to see the usage reports but the graphics shows noone view sites.(In site settings > Popularity Trends ) In crawling I make it continuously. How can I make it work?

Comment: I hope this answers your question. http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/empty-usage-and-health-reports-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

There are certain conditions which you have to check to solve this issue

1. First, confirm if the option `enabled usage data collection` is enabled

[image]

2. Check whether the `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing` and `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import` timer jobs are all running.

[image]

http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/empty-usage-and-health-reports-in-sharepoint-2013/

https://guidesharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/enabling-usage-reportsharepoint-2013/